How do I highlight all cells that are within +/-10 of each other?
I need to compare the numerical value of the cells in a column to each other. If two or more cells are within +/- 10 of each other I need to highlight all of those cells.
eg. C1 = 1234555, C2 = 1234567, C3 = 1234573, C4 = 1234583, C5 = 1234596
Because C2, C3 & C4 are all within the +/-10 range, they all need to be highlighted but not C1 or C5.
Note: I know it's through conditional formatting but I don't know what the formula would be.
Thanks

Another way for sorted/unsorted lists can be:
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$100,">="&A1-10,$A$1:$A$100,"<="&A1+10)>1




Note: I know it's through conditional formatting but I don't know what the formula would be.

You'd just need to keep track of the current range of cells. When C2 is selected, the range would be ±10 of that cell's value. Then, when you find that C3 is in that range, you need to expand the range to be [1234557, 1234573], and so on. There's no single formula because the range changes as add more cells to the selection.
Common sense suggests sorting the cells by value. Then, start with the selected cell and expand in each direction until you find a difference greater than 10. So:
C1 = 1234555
C2 = 1234567
C3 = 1234573
C4 = 1234583
C5 = 1234596

The list is already sorted. If you start with C2, the difference between C1 and C2 is more than 10, so C2 is the lower bound. Moving in the increasing direction, the first gap greater than 10 is between C4 and C5, so exclude C5. The selected cells should be C2, C3, C4.

I understand that ... but because I have a lot of data I need to highlight those cells so that they are easily identifiable at a glance.

Didn't notice the [tag:google-sheets] -- can't help you with that part.

You can compare the value with its next one and previous one. Since you're starting from C1, I suggest you use OFFSET and IFERROR, so the first and last row are also considered:
=AND(C1<>"",OR(IFERROR(ABS(C1-OFFSET(C1,1,0))<=10),IFERROR(ABS(C1-OFFSET(C1,-1,0))<=10)))


